# how to remove grayscale of one element if it's a property of the body

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.body.style.filter = 'grayscale(100%)'
        document.getElementById('logout').style.filter = 'none' 
        setOpacity('opacity-100');
      });
    } else {
      setOpacity('opacity-0');
      
    }
  }, [isOpen]);
```

i am making a react app and there is a popup that comes when we try to logout what i want is for the background to be in grayscale but the popup should retain it's colour

i tried many thing but nothing worked like i don't know how i can remove the grayscale set on body from one element

Comment: You can not "reverse" the effect of a grayscale filter for descendant elements. If you move all your body content into an additional container div, so that you can then apply the filter to that container, and append your popup element to body _outside_ of the container, that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the "backdrop-filter" attribute instead of the "filer" attribute，This requires some changes in your layout，You can refer to this link. https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000042999615